# Rudin's RCA, Theorem $2.18$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

These are the definitions which we need for the theorem :
[image]

[image]

[image]

There is the theorem and it's proof:
[image]

I don't understand Why is there a regular measure $\mu$ which satisfies the conclusions of theorem $2.17$?
It will  be regular by $2.14$ theorem but I don't understand why does it satisfy the all conclusions of the $2.17$ theorem.
In $2.17$ theorem we have $\sigma$-compact Hausdorff space.
in $2.18$ we have Hausdorff space in which every open set is $\sigma$-compact. Does this implies that $X$ is $\sigma$-compact?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $\mu(V) = \mu((V-F)\cup F) = \mu(V-F) + \mu(F) < \varepsilon + \mu(F)$

Comment: @Meowdog thank you . Please answer on the second question too

Comment: Maybe the difference is that $X$ in Theorem 2.17 is $\sigma$-compact...

Comment: @Meowdog yes that’s the difference.

Comment: That’s why i didn’t get the proof

Comment: Every open set in $X$ is $\sigma$-compact, in particular $X$ itself is $\sigma$-compact, since $X$ is open in $X$.

Comment: @Vit Thank you.